# "runjags" R package run.jags function parallel method. How many cores do the parallel method used?

Tags: r, jags, runjags

I have used the run.jags function to perform parallel processing. How many cores have been used during the processing? My computer has 4 cores, can I specify run.jags to use all the 4 cores, only use 2 or 3 cores etc.?

Comment: How have you called `run.jags`.  What `method` settings have you used?  You need to provide *far* more detail before we can help you effectively.

Comment: the method used is "parallel", n.chains is 3.